# Magento 2: Issue when creating Magento Plugin for overriding GetSelectionTitlePrice method

Tags: magento2, bundled-product

I 've created the following plugin to override a method located at 
`vendor/magento/module-bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle/Option.php` 
but it still does not seem to sort the desired effect. Any ideas on how this could work as desired?

> app/code/MySpace/MyModule/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option">
        <plugin name="bundle-product-option-radio" type="MySpace\MyModule\Plugin\RadioPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/MySpace/MyModule/Plugin/RadioPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace MySpace\MyModule\Plugin;

class RadioPlugin
{

     public function aroundGetSelectionQtyTitlePrice(
        \Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $selection,
        $includeContainer = true)
    {
        $this->setFormatProduct($selection);
        $priceTitle = '<span class="product-name">'
            . $this->escapeHtml($selection->getName())
            . '</span>';
        return $priceTitle;
    }
}
```

The method to override is located at `vendor/magento/module-bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle/Option.php`:

```
/**
 * Get bundle option price title.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $selection
 * @param bool $includeContainer
 * @return string
 */
public function getSelectionQtyTitlePrice($selection, $includeContainer = true)
{
    $this->setFormatProduct($selection);
    $priceTitle = '<span class="product-name">'
        . $selection->getSelectionQty() * 1
        . ' x '
        . $this->escapeHtml($selection->getName())
        . '</span>';

    $priceTitle .= ' &nbsp; ' . ($includeContainer ? '<span class="price-notice">' : '') .
        '+' .
        $this->renderPriceString($selection, $includeContainer) . ($includeContainer ? '</span>' : '');

    return $priceTitle;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use $subject instead of $this in function block to refer Core 
class object.

```
 public function aroundGetSelectionQtyTitlePrice(
    \Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $selection,
    $includeContainer = true)
{
    $subject->setFormatProduct($selection);
    $priceTitle = '<span class="product-name">'
        . $subject->escapeHtml($selection->getName())
        . '</span>';
    return $priceTitle;
}
```